# How do we can override or extend components in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I need a piece of advice, we create an application for users that can be customized for a specific client. 
For example, we create our app for a customer A and let's imagine we have: a *blue button* with *a text "Send"* and *a letter image* near to the text
Then a customer B says, that he needs this button like this: *red button* with *a text "Email us"* and *an arrow image* near to the text

This is just a super simple example, we can have much more changes and with huge components.

We think this way, to create a first default app for customer A, all components and other stuff will be in common folders like we have only this app at all.
Then to create a folder for the customer B, there we will put only override components, for example, Button.js

We need help to understand how should we to override or inherit properly a component (for our case a button component) from the default one?

Comment: Component has `props`. You can control appearance of the component trough props. For more complex components -- you can derive them.

Comment: Could you please explain with an example? Because I cannot catch it how to use props in this case. We have a common folder with components, there we have for example Button.js with code. In App.js we add it in our app. Then we add a folder let's say customerB and there we have also a components folder with Button.js this component can have the same methods and other common logic but have some differents as I mentioned above. We should implement Button.js from customerB folder in App.js (depends on some config values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React you can define a component with some properties. So, it's possible to create reusable components, not just split your code into modules. (You can even pack your components library an publish as NPM package for better dependency management).

When you use the component, you just provide those properties. And the same component renders or behaves differently.

#### Parametrised component (by using `props`)

```js
export const Button = props => 
    <div>{props.text}</div>;
```

```
.button {
  // CSS styles here
}

.button--red {
  // CSS styles here
}

.button--icon-arrow {
  // CSS styles here
}
```

Then you use your component somewhere:

```
<Button text="Email us" className="button button--red button--icon-arrow" />
```

#### Derived components (classes inheritance)

First, you define the base component `<Button />`.

Then you derive `<AlertButton />` from `<Button />` and override the functionality.

```js
export class Button extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <button onClick={this.onClick}>{this.props.text}</button>;
    }

    onClick = e => {
        console.log(e);
    };
}

export class AlertButton extends Button {
    onClick = e => {
        alert(5);
    };
}
```

Then you can use both components separately in different ways.

```
<Button text="console.log()" />
<AlertButton text="alert()" />
```

Check out the materials:

1. [React Docs / Components and Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)
2. [CSS Tricks / BEM 101](https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/)